# Redirect stderr for seperate files running simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, logging, stderr

I have a script that runs continuously in the terminal and I have redirected the stderr in that file to a log file:

```
sys.stderr = open('redirect/log/file.log', 'a')
```

This works as expected. While the program is running in the background all errors that occur in the script get sent to the log file.

However, when I am working on a completely separate script in Python, the stderr of the work I am doing gets sent to that same log file. For example when I write

```
raise ValueError('error')
```

in the file that I am working on, nothing appears in the console and instead gets sent to that log file.

How can I isolate it so only the stderr of that script gets sent to a log file?

Ideally, the stderr of the program running continuously gets sent to the log and anything else running or currently being worked on in Python works normally.

To visualize, I am using the Pycharm IDE working on a package. I have a terminal window running a script within the package  that does calculations in a while loop(continuously). The stderr is explicitly redirected within that script using the code above. Then I have another file within the package that I am working on that is not being used at all by the script that is running. Any errors that I incur while working on this separate script are not being shown within the console, but instead being sent to the log file of the other running script.

Comment: Can you add more details? I don't quite see how a *completely separate* script will write to the same log file unless you specifically tell it to.

Comment: @kazemakase I edited my question. Some additional information. It also does not make sense to me. Maybe it it setting the stderr of the whole package?

Comment: Why do you do Pyhton-side stderr redirection, as opposed to using shell redirection? That is, `python myscript.py 2> errors.log`?

Comment: @Joe: stderr is set for _the whole OS process_. Everything running under the same Python interpreter will share it.

Comment: @9000 Ok great. Will the shell redirection above work on Windows? Or even better is there a way within the script I can redirect the stderr specifically for that script?

Comment: @9000 I confirm that the `python myscript.py 2> errors.log` works on Windows. However, I'd still rather not have to type the whole path to the log file every time.

Comment: The right way for a script would be to allow an explicit output file parameter, or to use e.g. `logging` so that its specific logger could be configured differently. If all the script does is writing to stdout, I'm afraid the only option to have that script to write to a different file than other code running _simultaneously_ with it is to use two separate processes. In the shell, you can define a variable and write `myscript 2> %NAME_OF_LOG_FILE%` (on Windows).